# PHP Symfony3, listener on instantiating a new entity

Tags: php, symfony, listener, instantiation, symfony-3.3

I would like to trigger on an instantiation of a new entity.
**Can someone say if it is possible, and how ?**
Waiting for an issue, I bring this solution in getting a new entity in a service… but I find it not enough optimized.
Here is (simplified extract of) my code with an added event "onCreate" in listener :
This is running well, but I have to call a new entity, passing by a service. I want my new entity filled directly while just doing "$entity = new entity();"

```
abstract class serviceBaseEntity extends serviceBaseClass {

const ENTITY_CLASS = ''; // here class of entity

protected $classname;
protected $shortname;
protected $EntityManager;
protected $ObjectManager;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, RequestStack $request_stack) {
    parent::__construct($container, $request_stack);
    $this->EntityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $this->ObjectManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $this->addEventSubscriber(new serviceAnnotations($container, $request_stack));
    $this->classname = $this->calledClassname::ENTITY_CLASS;
    $this->shortname = (new ReflectionClass($this->classname))->getShortName();
    return $this;
}

protected function addEventSubscriber(EventSubscriber $EventSubscriber) {
    $this->EntityManager->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber($EventSubscriber);
    return $this;
}

    public function getNew() {
    $entity = new $this->classname;
    $eventArgs = new LifecycleEventArgs($entity, $this->ObjectManager);
    $this->EntityManager->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent(AnnotationsBase::onCreate, $eventArgs);
    return $entity;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the logic of the application and the reason why it's necessary to have this kind of event, but want to recommend to have a look [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)
You probably could use prePersist event as long as creation by itself doesn't have any effect on the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Vlad :)
The reason is to fill some fields with default data from container, database or anything else (for example, the "locale", kept in config.yml, thru de controller->getParameters(…))
This can be cool, while using a create form with a new entity

Comment: You can take a look on Doctrine Lifecycle Events. Maybe this will help you.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Comment: May be you should use a factory then, not events? Your factory would take care of all of the possible default values and you can inject there which ever service you want. I don't think that it's possible to create an event for a construction like:
new EntityClass();

Comment: Yes. I don't think it is possible to trigger on a new entity…
So, for the moment, the solution of using a service for getting a new entity is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a sort of factory method in your entity, with a private constructor. For example:

```
Class MyEntity {
    private function __construct( ) {
        your code
    }
    public static function createEntity(your params) {
           do some stuff
           $e=new MyEntity();
           do some other stuff
           return $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you create a new instance of an entity class, then use a method on that class to create yet another new instance of the same class with data set? Feels dirty. Just make a factory class if that's what you need. Pass in values, validate, etc, then create entity class and set data - or create with `new MyEntity($param1, $param2)` and pass them to constructor in the entity class